# Don't append newline when redirection program's output to a file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a program which list files of a directory, when there is not a file, it output is empty, but if `program > output.txt`, there is a newline in this file, so can not use `test -s output.txt` to judge if the directory is empty. how to resolve this problem, there is not wc command at my system, but sed, sort, grep are OK, thanks!

Comment: What is the program you're using to produce the input? The redirection operator does not produce a newline by itself.

Comment: @PS it looks like wc -l, is it?

Comment: @merlin2011 it is rsync --list-only script with some grep command, thanks!

Comment: @netawater yes, you would have to check if number of empty lines is zero or not and as per it put conditions.

Comment: Do you have the `tr` command available?

Comment: @merlin2011 no tr command, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you cannot use `wc`. You can use the following command to print the number of non-empty lines.

```
grep -c . inputfile
```

To print the number of empty lines:

```
grep -vc . inputfile
```